# In Elastic search how to filter result set on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

can someone help with my search query on how I can filter the results based on 2 fields? I have built an Index with 1000's of documents init and from the UI we will be calling this Index and it consists of 2 search fields

1. Search by Zipcode
2. and search by city/state

Based on these combinations we need to show results only within that zip code.

***Mapping***

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "state": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "zipcode": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "startdate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "enddate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "customerstatus": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "customerid": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

***Query***

```
 {
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "32081",
            "fields": ["address.zipcode" ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "FL",
            "fields": ["address.cityname","address.state" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***Result set***

```
{
    "customerid":1,
    "customerstatus": Active,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2020-07-15",
    "enddate": "2021-07-15" 
},
{
    "customerid":2,
    "customerstatus": Pending,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2018-01-01",
    "enddate": "2019-01-01" 
},
{
    "customerid":3,
    "customerstatus": Pending,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2020-06-01",
    "enddate": "2021-06-01" 
},
{
    "customerid":4,
    "customerstatus": Pending,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2021-01-01",
    "enddate": "2022-01-01" 
},
{
    "customerid":5,
    "customerstatus": Inactive,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2020-07-15",
    "enddate": "2021-07-15" 
},
{
    "customerid":6,
    "customerstatus": cancelled,
    "address": {
                        "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
                        "state": "FL",
                        "zipcode": "32081"
                    },
    "startdate": "2020-07-15",
    "enddate": "2021-07-15" 
}
```

***Now the requirement is in a way that,***

1. *Exclude the results where customerstatus is Inactive and Cancelled (Customer 5 and 6 shouldn't be displayed)*
2. *Display only Active and Pending*
3. *If Status is Pending then display the customers where the enddate is <500 days old and enddate not greater than 91 days*

**So, how can I get only customerid 1 and 3 in my result set.**

Comment: @ESCoder can you also please take a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) along with [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) to find documents on the basis of a range of days. Try out this below query

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "customerstatus": "pending"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "enddate": {
                    "gt": "now-500d/d",
                    "lte": "now+91d/d"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "customerstatus": "active"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "terms": {
          "customerstatus.keyword": [
            "Inactive",
            "cancelled"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.6931472,
        "_source": {
          "customerid": 3,
          "customerstatus": "Pending",
          "address": {
            "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
            "state": "FL",
            "zipcode": "32081"
          },
          "startdate": "2020-06-01",
          "enddate": "2021-06-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67260491",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.5404451,
        "_source": {
          "customerid": 1,
          "customerstatus": "Active",
          "address": {
            "city": "PONTE VEDRA",
            "state": "FL",
            "zipcode": "32081"
          },
          "startdate": "2020-07-15",
          "enddate": "2021-07-15"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @RK Gaz added the answer. Please go through this and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: I will give try this and let you know :)

Comment: Apologies @ESCoder, last night I couldn't try but now I was able to try and I am getting the following error.

{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parse_exception",
                "reason": "unit [/] not supported for date math [-540/d]"
            }
        ],

Comment: @RKGaz which version of ES are you using ? Are you getting this query on running the same search query as shown above in the answer ?

Comment: we are using version 7.x ones. Yes, we are getting the error when we try the same query. But, i was able to by pass that error when i replace this,

{
                "range": {
                  "enddate": {
                    "gt": "now-500d/d",
                    "lte": "now+91d/d"
                  }
                }
              }

with 

{
                "range": {
                  "enddate": {
                    "gte": "09/01/2018",
     "format": "mm/dd/yyyy",
                    "lte": "06/30/2021"
                  }
                }
              }

Comment: currently the dates are being passed from UI, I thought I can auto calculate them in ES query. But, I really appreciate that you looked into my request.

Comment: testing has failed and when I check the actual index that was built, I came to know the range is not working because the field type is given as "text" instead of "date".

Is there any kind of conversion that we can make the field type from text to date? we can't drop the index and re-create it because of historical data init.